# What is the default return value of the getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek method in Java?

Tags: java, calendar

I searched but am not able to find the default value of `getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek()` in the `Calender` class of java. I have not set anything like locale etc. I would like to know what is the default minimal days in first week. Unfortunately I cannot run the code and check myself as it is on the server on which I have access just to read.

Answer (score 2):

`Calendar.getInstance()`, which returns `GregorianCalendar` (usually) constructs `Calendar` object using default locale:

```
protected Calendar()
{
    this(TimeZone.getDefaultRef(), Locale.getDefault());
    sharedZone = true;
}
```

then the following code is executed:

```
private void setWeekCountData(Locale desiredLocale)
{
   /* try to get the Locale data from the cache */
   int[] data = cachedLocaleData.get(desiredLocale);
   if (data == null) { /* cache miss */
      ResourceBundle bundle = LocaleData.getCalendarData(desiredLocale);
      data = new int[2];
      data[0] = Integer.parseInt(bundle.getString("firstDayOfWeek"));
      data[1] = Integer.parseInt(bundle.getString("minimalDaysInFirstWeek"));
      cachedLocaleData.putIfAbsent(desiredLocale, data);
   }
   firstDayOfWeek = data[0];
   minimalDaysInFirstWeek = data[1];
}
```

So - `minimalDaysInFirstWeek` is retrieved from compiled resource bundles from package `sun.util.resources`, from `CalendarData_<locale>.class` (on Oracle JVM).

For example, for Polish locale we have:

```
public final class CalendarData_pl extends LocaleNamesBundle
{
  protected final Object[][] getContents()
  {
    return new Object[][] { { "firstDayOfWeek", "2" }, { "minimalDaysInFirstWeek", "4" } };
  }
}
```

Comment: so is there always some locale based on where the code is compiled or is there something like default locale which has a default `minimalDaysInFirstWeek` value?

Comment: Locale is (usually) defined in the environment before java process starts. In Unix it may be defined using `export LC_ALL=pl_PL` command. In Windows you can use something in control panel. So the *default locale* is not Java-specific.

Answer (score 0):

usually the gregorian calendar is used and calculated with [https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gau%C3%9Fsche_Wochentagsformel] (didn't find a proper english version on wikipedia :'/) [1](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gau%C3%9Fsche_Wochentagsformel)
So, the minimal values may result from this formula OR per convention (01.01.1900 for example)

Seems I have misread your question. Hopefully the link provides some insight on the theoretical aspect.

Comment: Thanks it does give the theory but I was looking for a more specific answer how java does that calculation